# Will there be a 2.0.0.RELEASE of spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server-local or is there a new way to create a local server?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Spring Cloud Data Flow 2.0 came out a week ago but the Local Server is still on `1.7.4.RELEASE` on maven central as well as the starter for it. I'd like to know if there will be a new release of `spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server-local` or should I create the local server differently? (It is a requirement to have it in the project as a separate module rather than a separate imported jar.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In v2.0, we have consolidated to ship a single-server for all the supported platforms (i.e., Local, CF, and K8s). It is the same binary that can work across all of them.

You should look for `spring-cloud-dataflow-server` in Spring Repo and Maven Central going forward.

Please read the [v2.0 release blog](https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/06/spring-cloud-data-flow-and-skipper-2-0-ga-released) for more details.